# Modified by Community. What was the modification on this question?

Tags: support

This question showed up in the feed marked modified by community.  It's in active right now.  I looked at it and can't figure what the bot modified to get it to show up.  Can someone tell me how I can figure this out in the future?

[Here's the question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/17789/2003-nissan-frontier-pick-up-4-cylinder)

Comment: Related on MSE: [What can cause a question to be bumped?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped)

Answer (score 4):

Community is designed to kick up unanswered questions (positive question score, no positive-score answers) every now and again to bring it back to our attention.

It used to be very common to see this kind of behavior before our massive cleanup drive last month, so it's little surprise that we don't see such modifications as often as before.

Comment: Yup, completely understand that component of community and what it does.  Normally, I can see what community has edited to a question/answer   do drive into active.  In this case, it was a mystery to me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think "Community" has to really modify anything. I would bet (and this is just a guess) that the system uses the "last modified date" as to whether the question is active. Community wouldn't have to *change* anything outwardly to update this field in the database. In doing so it will bring the question to the foreground and out of the shadows.

This is just my take on it, but would bet it's something along these lines.

Comment: Yeah, it's interesting.  Sometimes I see an edit and can go look at the edits and sometimes it's like this.  No edits, states that it's modified by community and it's in the active cue now.  Weird.